# On how many days will Adam and Ben have rest-days on the same day?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

> Adam and Ben start their new jobs on the same day.Adam's schedule is
>   $3$ workdays followed by $1$ rest day.Ben's schedule is $7$ workdays
>   followed by $3$ rest days.On how many of their fist $1000$ days do
>   both have rest-days on the same day ?

**My effort**

Let $A,B$ stands for Adam and Ben schedules respectively,then

\begin{array}
\space A  &\equiv 1 \mod 3 \\
B & \equiv 3 \mod 7 \\
\end{array}

I am looking for the solution of the system
\begin{array}
\space 3q+1 &= 7j+3 \\
3q &=7j +2 \\
\end{array}

From this it follows that 
\begin{array}
\space 7j+2 &\equiv 0 \mod 3 \\
 6j+j+1 &\equiv 0 \mod 3 \\
j &\equiv 1 \mod 3 \\
\end{array}

So $j=1,7,10,13,16,\cdots $ I know that I must have an upper limit of $j <143$ since $j \cdot 143 >1000$

The solution is therefore $142$.

> **Question** I've not the possibility to check the correctness of the solution elsewhere,so I would like if someone could verify this out.

Comment: I think it is easier if you note that after a twenty-day period, the pattern restarts. So write down explicitly what the first twenty days look like, then multiply by $50$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,but I haven't clear one thing :why does my strategy overcounts the days ?I don't take care of some cases(I've realized it now) so I should have less days  than the actual days of rest-days.

Comment: Try using such a strategy over a $20$-day period and you'll clearly see where it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of $1000$ days, Adam rests on any $4j$-th day, where $j$ goes from $1$ to $250$.

Ben instead rests on days $10k + 8, 10k + 9, 10k + 10$ where $k$ goes from $0$ to $99$.

Noticing that $\operatorname{mcm}(4,10) = 20$, it is straightforward to see that the solution is $K\cdot \frac{1000}{20} = 50K$, where $K$ is the number of common rest days in the first $20$ days.

How many are those? Adam rests on days $4,8,12,16,20$ and Ben rests on days $8,9,10,18,19,20$. So $K=2$ and the solution is $100$.